# onUtterenceCompleteListener does not doing the task

Tags: android

i am writing a app where i want to print a toast after completion of text to speech and here is my code

```
if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    tts = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this,
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

                        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                            Log.e("error", "This Language is not supported");
                        } else {

                            tts.speak("speak new or retrieve",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                            tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new 
OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onUtteranceCompleted(String arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method
                                            // stub

                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  
"done........", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
```

but after the speech the toast is not appearing.please help....

Answer (score 0):

You need to call speak with the parameter key KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID to identify an utterance in the TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener after text has been spoken.

The call should be like this:

```
tts.speak("speak new or retrieve",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, new HashMap<String,String>()
    {{ 
          put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
              what_do_you_want_to_play_utterance_id);
    }} 
 ));
```

I suggest also setting tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener() before the call to speak().